# Update Visual Studio 2008 C# Project to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I'm trying to update an custom software used at a friend's business that was built in 2008. I have a copy of the source code, but I'm not able to compile it. I've dual booted my macbook so that I can work on the project (made for windows) in a windows environment, since the project wont show me errors nor compile in the visual studio i have on my mac.

The program is currently running and working (as an exe file) at their business, but is running VERY slow so I'm trying to update the system and clean up their SQL server. The issue is, I'm struggling to navigate the project and get it to compile, and I'm not sure yet how or what to search.

A few questions with screenshots attached below:

1. How do I figure out what kind of project I'm working with? I recognize that this console project was written in c#, but I know there are many ways to write and I'm not sure what to be searching to help me debug this type of project. I've attached the first error messages, as well as a screenshot from the sln file showing that it is a 2008 visual studio project.
2. What are the first files you would look through to get your bearings in custom software? I used to work as a software engineer, so I'm comfortable navigate c#, but I'm struggling to figure out where to look in a bigger, custom project like this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are looking at is VS saying:

> I don't know how to compile to target .NET Framework 4.0.

You have two ways to "resolve" the issue:

1. Install an older version of Visual Studio that includes a Targeting Pack for .NET Framework 4.0 (from what I can find, the most recent would be VS 2019).
2. Upgrade the `TargetFramework` in all project files to at least .NET Framework 4.6

If your goal is to work out performance issues and you're going blind, I'd recommand starting with profiling the running application. This is going to show you the application's critical path in addition to what is taking the most time.

Comment: @RJCarrier Hello, have the above two solutions solved your issue?

Comment: Yes! That moved me on to other errors!